# What is the full width of a peak of the function $F(X)=\frac{1+\cos((2N+1)πX)}{1+\cos(πX)}$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives

With $$1 + \cos \theta = 2 \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2},$$ the function becomes $$f_n(x) = \left( \frac{\cos \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2}}{\cos \frac{\pi x}{2}} \right)^2.$$

It peaks at odd X integer values.

What is the width of a maximum-full width ?
I have trouble finding when the function is 0 (or min) around the peak. The max is at 0/0 positions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the places where the numerator is zero:

$$\cos \frac{(2n+1)\pi x}{2} = 0 \to x = \frac{(2m+1)\pi}{2}.$$

Now pick your favorite two adjacent integers $m,m+1$ and calculate the difference in $x$.

Comment: Arent those positions giving 0/0 and thus the function peaks there ?